# Free swap file space contained on root partition without rebooting to free space checked by df

Tags: ram, swap, disk-usage, memory-usage, df

I have created a temporary Swap file (`/var/cache/swap/myswap`) of 500GB on a Ubuntu worstation at work wiht 1TB RAM. This swapfile is on a BTRFS filesystem.

I don't need anymore of this swapfile now and I would like that space taken by this swapfile doesn't appear anymore when I do a "`df`" command.

I would like to free this space without rebooting.

I tried : `$ swapoff -a`

I have also tried : `$ swapoff /var/cache/swap/myswap`

I have removed too basically the file `/var/cache/swap/myswap`

But still space 500GB are taken into account when I do a `df` command (I have still 64% root partition "`/`" instead of 10% when there is not swapfile of 500GB)

How could I make really this swapfile to not be taken into account with `df` command without having to reboot ? I mean, that Swapfile removing to be effective.

Comment: Did you `rm` the file?

Comment: @Nmath . Yes, I removed it as I said but the display of memory with `df` didn't update, that's weird.

Comment: There is likely a cache that prevents it from updating right away. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8485